# Show closest class is not working

Tags: jquery

HTML:

```
<html><head>
    <title>Form validation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/fonts/style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validation.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">

  First name:<br>

  <input type="text" class="require" name="firstname"> 
  <div class="error">
     <p><span class="icon-cross"> </span> This field is required </p> 
  </div>

  <div class="success">
     <p><span class="icon-checkmark"> This field is required</span></p> 
  </div>


  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">
<br>
<div class="raio-group require">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
</div>
<br>
<textarea class="require"></textarea>

  <br><br>
  <input class="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 


</body></html>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.submit_btn').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.require').each(function(){
            THIS = $(this); // THIS - global variable. if THIS is followed by 'var' it willl be local here
            if(is_empty())
                set_warning();
            else
                unset_warning();
        });

    });
});


function is_empty(){

    if(THIS.hasClass('raio-group'))
        return radio_is_unchecked();    
    else
        return is_value_not_set();
}

function radio_is_unchecked(){

    var name = THIS.find("input").attr("name");

    if($("input:radio[name="+name+"]:checked").length == 0)
       return true;

    return false;
}

function is_value_not_set(){

    var input_value = THIS.val();

    return !$.trim(input_value).length > 0 ;
}

function set_warning(){
    console.log(THIS.closest('.error').show());
}
function unset_warning(){
    THIS.removeClass('error');
    THIS.addClass('success');
}



THIS.closest('.error').show() line should show the nearest .error div. should n't? Whats wrong is going on my code?
```

Comment: Do you know that you can pass arguments to functions?

Comment: Yes. I know. But what problem if I deal a global variable without passing argument?

Comment: @AbdusSattarBhuiyan, how many error `div`s do you have ? Only 1 ?

Comment: Yes. Right now i am testing only one div.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `THIS`: it has the expected element. The issue is that none of these elements has an ancestor with the class "error" -- which is what `closest` will be looking for (despite its name).

You seem to be looking for a next *sibling* element with that class. You can do that with:

```
THIS.nextAll('.error').eq(0).show()
```

Make sure however to have an `error` class element following all the mandatory input elements, or you will be addressing the wrong one.

Comment: Won't `.get(0)` give the DOM node, so `.show()` won't be available?   Either `.first().show()` or re-wrap the get(0) in `$()`

Comment: Indeed, changed to `eq`. Thanks for noting, @freedomn-m!